# How to save Radio buttons and checkbox to localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save input type="radio" and "checkbox" to localStorage and also get same values from localStorage. For other input fields like text and select elements it is working but for radio and checkbox it is not saving. Can you please help me with the code.

## Saving to localstorage

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    let value = $(this).val();
    localStorage.setItem(id, value);
  });
```

## loading from localstorage

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    let value = localStorage.getItem(id);
    $(this).val(value);
    
  });



<input name="row8unit3grade" type="radio" value="5">A
<input name="row8unit3grade" type="radio" value="4">B
<input name="row8unit3grade" type="radio" value="3">C

<input name="row8unit2grade" type="radio" value="5">A
<input name="row8unit2grade" type="radio" value="4">B
<input name="row8unit2grade" type="radio" value="3">C
```

Like this we have 15 sets of radiobuttons with different names. We need to store all radiobuttons at-a-time top localstorage after clicking save. and get all values after clicking restore

Comment: that's because your code is just: for every input type radio, save to localStorage (key, value) => ($id, $value). This obviously didn't work because you're just saving ALL RADIO VALUES (rather than only the selected/checked ones). This makes localstorage hold the value of last radio input rather than selected radio input.

Comment: Adding to kristian's comment, you should be using `name` attribute than `id`.

Comment: Do you have different groups with radio buttons, or just one group?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Saving data to localStorage

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            let id = $(this).attr('name');
            let value = $(this).val();
            console.log(value);
            localStorage.setItem(id, value);
            
        }
    });
```

## Getting data from localstorage

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    let id = $(this).attr('name');
    var radios = document.getElementsByName(id); // list of radio buttons
var val = localStorage.getItem(id); // local storage value
console.log(val);
for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++){
  if(radios[i].value == val){
      radios[i].checked = true; // marking the required radio as checked
  }
}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your radio buttons by the name `row8unit3grade` and `row8unit2grade`. and check if anyone is checked and then save to local storage.

```
<input type="radio" name="row8unit3grade" class="grade" value="5">A
<input type="radio" name="row8unit3grade" class="grade" value="4">B
<input type="radio" name="row8unit3grade" class="grade" value="3">C

<input type="radio" name="row8unit2grade" class="grade2" value="5">A
<input type="radio" name="row8unit2grade" class="grade2" value="4">B
<input type="radio" name="row8unit2grade" class="grade2" value="3">C

<button id="save">Save</button>
<button id="restore">Restore</button>

$(document).on('click','#save',function(){
    $('input[name="row8unit3grade"]:checked').each(function() {
        let id = $(this).attr('name');
        let value = $(this).val();
        localStorage.setItem(id, value);
        return false;
    });
    $('input[name="row8unit2grade"]:checked').each(function() {    
        let id = $(this).attr('name');
        let value = $(this).val();
        localStorage.setItem(id, value);
    });
});

$(document).on('click','#restore',function(){
    $('input[name="row8unit3grade"]:checked').each(function() {
        let id = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = localStorage.getItem(id);
        alert(value);
    });
    $('input[name="row8unit2grade"]:checked').each(function() {
        let id = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = localStorage.getItem(id);
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gb2ouLtp/1/)

Comment: could you please seperate setItem and getItem logic and showcase

Comment: When do you want to get?

Comment: setItem after clicking save button and getItem after clicking restore button?

Comment: What is the code if we have multiple radio inputs with different names
<input type="radio" name="cat" value="ABC" />MNP
<input type="radio" name="cat" value="DEF" />PQR

Comment: Can you put your HTML in question? so i can check more.

Comment: Please put in question.

Comment: Thanks for giving me idea. Anyway I have posted answer which works for me. I have created array and stored radiobutton names for getting the values from numerous radiobuttons. Thanks for helping me and giving suggestions